# Long location is unnecessarily truncated on user's profile page

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, profile-page, location

Really long locations are truncated on users' profile pages. As [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan), for example:

[image]

Instead of the full location, it's cut off and the last few characters are replaced by an ellipsis. On the other hand, viewing this same user on the ['moderators' tab](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) has no issues:

[image]

That user's location is 33 characters long. On the other hand, [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) user has a 34 character location, which is uninterrupted (the last comma at the end isn't a cutoff, just a typo or something):

[image]

Highlighting the text and copying it does seem to copy the whole text, even what's hidden by the truncation.

I did a bit of testing, and it seems to be that a location with no spaces that is longer than 30 characters is cut off and reduced to just 28 (probably to accommodate the three ellipsis dots). The number of spaces does adjust the specifics, but that isn't the important part, which is the fact that we have plenty of pixelic [?] real estate on that page, at least on the desktop view. We could easily have 100 character location-names and the spot still wouldn't feel cramped.

I'm not sure why this has been cut off, but I don't think it would do any harm to extend that line and accommodate longer locations. Especially if people live in Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch.

(I don't know if this should be a bug or a feature-request, so I've just tagged both.)